# у меня в приложении на Google карте маркеры

Tags: java, android

у меня в приложении на Google карте маркеры видны в радиусе 100 метров как сделать так чтобы когда я передвигался карта автоматически обновлялась и показала маркеры,я пишу код на java или сделать так что бы карта каждые 5 секунд обновилась.помогите,можете показать пример кода?

Comment: Вызывай через timer метод который обновляет метку.

Comment: можете показать пример,если не сложно

Comment: ?????можете показать пример кода???